# Is there a CPAN module listing U.S. ZIP codes and states?

Tags: perl, perl-module, zipcode

Basically, I am looking for a module that can tell me:

1. All the ZIP codes in a given state
2. Whether a given ZIP code is in a given state
3. The state to which a given ZIP code belongs

I would prefer this to be standalone, so I don't pull a whole bunch of dependencies.

I am basically asking this because I am about to generate a module using [this file I found on the U.S. Census Bureau web site](http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt), and I don't want to waste time on it if something suitable already exists.

I am not going to look up city names by ZIP code, so I don't care that, e.g., the Tiger file thinks `14850` is just for Ithaca College, but then I also don't know if there are other problems with that file.

If you don't know of a suitable CPAN module, I would also appreciate naming suggestions for such a module, and better sources of data.

I have a feeling the USPS wants to charge for a proper list, and the [U.S. Census Bureau is not interested](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tigermap.html#ZIP):

> In the past, the Census Bureau produced the 1990 Gazetteer ZIP Code file and a 1999 ZIP Code file. These files were produced as byproducts of Census Bureau internal operations. They were not developed as a formal product. However, the Census Bureau has made them available to the public "as is". There will be no updated versions of these files.

Comment: (The Canadian gov is actually suing an effort to create an open database of Canadian postal codes! What a waste of taxpayer money.)

Comment: @ikegami *sigh* Here's the story: http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20120416/10134118504/canada-post-claims-copyright-over-postal-codes-meets-resistance.shtml

Comment: That's where I first heard of it. Techdirt is awesome.

Comment: For #2 and #3, you only need to look at the first two digits of the zip code (except for Texarkana, AR).

Comment: @mob Wikipedia says *ZIP code 42223 spans Christian KY and Montgomery TN, and ZIP code 97635 spans Lake OR and Modoc CA.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#Primary_State_Prefixes

Comment: OK, there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U.S. Postal Service does give access to an [address information API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm). I am not sure how to respond to "What is the Web site address (URL) of the site that will be hosting the USPS Web Tools?" for the simple purpose of packaging a look up table, but I am mentioning it here in case someone else finds it useful.

Depending on the user's goals, one of the labeling lists found in [pe.usps.gov/text/LabelingLists/](http://pe.usps.com/Archive/HTML/DMMArchive20070717/labeling_lists.htm) might be suitable. It looks like I am going to use one of those tables as a first pass at reducing the number of cases to be examined.

Finally, [Twilio/Wigle.net Street Vector Data Set on Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/2408) might provide all the detail you might ever need, but I have not checked to see if you can list ZIP codes by states.

Comment: Geo::US::ZIPCode - For best coverage, also consult [module-authors](http://lists.perl.org/list/module-authors.html), [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node=Meditations), [PrePAN](http://prepan.org/)

Comment: The CPAN module could be called Acme::Mr_ZIP

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._ZIP

Comment: I think I wrote a module for that, but I didn't do that bit of the task. I also bought a CD of the postal data and it wasn't worth the price. But, make your own list by querying the Google Maps API enough times :) You might also like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53918/which-us-zipcodes-map-to-more-than-one-state-or-more-than-one-city

Comment: link is dead on the answer. here is a working link. https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm